# How does computing the determinant of a submatrix result in the inclusion of minors of ideals?

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra, ideals

[image]

I'm wondering how I can obtain the underlined inclusion? Also, would anyone be able to present a small example? I can see how $I_0(A)=R$, but I'm struggling to see what the other ideals should be.

Here is an example I was playing with myself:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&3&3\\ 2&5&6 \end{bmatrix},$ Then $I_{-\infty}(A)= \dots=I_{-1}(A)=I_0(A)=R$ . What is $I_1(A)$ and $I_2(A)$ since 1,2 are greater than $0$ but not $>2$? I also have $I_3(A)=\dots=I_\infty(A)=\langle 0\rangle$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The equation immediately before the underlined inclusion shows how every $r\times r$ minor is a linear combination (with coefficients in $R$) of $(r-1)\times(r-1)$ minors.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response!! I guess I'm questioning the relationship between the determinant of a minor compared to the the matrix A. I see that when comparing the determinant of an $r \times r$ is going to be greater than the determinant of an $(r-1)\times (r-1)$ matrix. So does the inclusion just following the ordering of the determinants?

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen I'm not sure what you mean by "greater" or by "ordering of the determinants", since there's no given ordering on the ring $R$ of scalars. The relevant ordering is just the inclusion ordering of ideals.

Comment: What if the ring is say $\mathbb{Z}$? I guess I'm having a hard timing seeing how the computation for $\det(B)$ will implies the needed inclusion?